# Saving Blank Excel Cells to Rails Postgres Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, import-from-excel, roo-gem

I've managed to get the Roo Gem working so that I can import an Excel file and save it to the database of my app. This has been successful a few times, but it appears that in spreadsheets that contain blanks in certain rows it brings up an error. My code is as follows:

require 'roo'

```
xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(File.expand_path('../Downloads/LOCATION.xlsx'))

xlsx.each_row_streaming(offset: 1) do |row|
    Location.find_or_create_by(ukprn: row[0]&.value, accomurl: row[1]&.value, instbeds: row[2]&.value, instlower: row[3]&.value, instupper: row[4]&.value, locid: row[5]&.value, name: row[6]&.value, lat: row[7]&.value, long: row[8]&.value, locukprn: row[9]&.value, loccountry: row[10]&.value, privatelower: row[11]&.value, privateupper: row[12]&.value, suurl: row[13]&.value)
end
```

I read that from Ruby 2.3.0 by including an `&` before the method it doesn't include nil method errors, so I was hoping this would work.

The first 4 rows seem to work fine but as it gets to a row with blanks in Below is a snippet of the error I get:

```
Location Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."ukprn" = $1 AND "locations"."accomurl" = $2 AND "locations"."instbeds" IS NULL AND "locations"."instlower" = $3 AND "locations"."instupper" = $4 AND "locations"."locid" = $5 AND "locations"."name" = $6 AND "locations"."lat" = $7 AND "locations"."long" IS NULL AND "locations"."locukprn" = $8 AND "locations"."loccountry" = $9 AND "locations"."privatelower" = $10 AND "locations"."privateupper" = $11 AND "locations"."suurl" = $12 LIMIT $13  [["ukprn", "10000055"], ["accomurl", "http://www.brookes.ac.uk/studying-at-brookes/accommodation/halls-in-detail/"], ["instlower", 4081], ["instupper", "4684"], ["locid", "6463"], ["name", "AB"], ["lat", "Abingdon &amp; Witney College (Abingdon Campus)"], ["locukprn", 51], ["loccountry", "-1.28696"], ["privatelower", 10000055], ["privateupper", "XF"], ["suurl", "4219"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "Abingdon &amp; Witney College (Abingdon Campus)"
: SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."ukprn" = $1 AND "locations"."accomurl" = $2 AND "locations"."instbeds" IS NULL AND "locations"."instlower" = $3 AND "locations"."instupper" = $4 AND "locations"."locid" = $5 AND "locations"."name" = $6 AND "locations"."lat" = $7 AND "locations"."long" IS NULL AND "locations"."locukprn" = $8 AND "locations"."loccountry" = $9 AND "locations"."privatelower" = $10 AND "locations"."privateupper" = $11 AND "locations"."suurl" = $12 LIMIT $13
    from /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:606:in `exec_prepared'
```

I assume that Postgres is not content with the null data being saved in the database and therefore the "Abingdon & Witney College (Abingdon Campus)" is moved to another column, because the relevant record is a string as shown in the migration record below:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.text :name
      t.decimal :lat
      t.decimal :long
      t.string :locid, index: true
      t.integer :locukprn
      t.string :loccountry
      t.integer :privatelower
      t.string :privateupper
      t.string :ukprn, index: true
      t.string :suurl
      t.string :accomurl
      t.integer :instbeds
      t.integer :instlower
      t.string :instupper
      t.references :institute, foreign_key: true, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Is this what's going wrong, and are there any suggestions as to how to solve this?

Comment: `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "Abingdon &amp; Witney College (Abingdon Campus)"` I may be reading this wrong but, this value is not a numeric?

Comment: But neither is the data in the schema, it's 'text' as it's under the 'name' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Select has:

```
[
 (0)["ukprn", "10000055"],
 (1)["accomurl", "http://www.brookes.ac.uk/studying-at-brookes/accommodation/halls-in-detail/"],
 (2)["instlower", 4081],
 (3)["instupper", "4684"],
 (4)["locid", "6463"],
 (5)["name", "AB"],
 (6)["lat", "Abingdon &amp; Witney College (Abingdon Campus)"],
 (7)["locukprn", 51],
 (8)["loccountry", "-1.28696"],
 (9)["privatelower", 10000055],
 (10)["privateupper", "XF"],
 (11)["suurl", "4219"],
 (12)["LIMIT", 1]
]
```

This lat value is not a numeric and your migration has `t.decimal :lat`

Comment: As stated in the above comment, that entry is in row 6 and therefore should be under 'name', which is format 'text' according to the migration.

Comment: It looks to me like the `find_or_create` has `locations.lat` pulling from `row[7]` and thus the `SELECT` does `"locations"."lat" = $7 ` The name is in 6 right?

Comment: Yes, it should be. "Abingdon &amp; Witney College (Abingdon Campus)" comes from row 6 of the spreadsheet though, hence why I don't understand the error.

Comment: I re-edited my post for more clarity. I would ask next if in excel `locid = 6463` and `name = "AB"` ?

Comment: No, locid would have been AB.

Comment: The query seems to be skipping certain columns, such as `instbeds` in [2] and therefore shifting all data to the left... is there a way to get around this?